# How to delay next async api call when an api doesn't respond?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, future, callable

I have a list of APIs that I have to asynchronously connect to and retrieve data. In that case, I'm creating a list of `callable` tasks. A callable class looks like:

```
public class ConnectToApiCallable implements Callable<ReturnedStringAndDate> {

*variables & constructor*

@Override
public ReturnedStringAndDate call() throws Exception {

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClientBuilder.create().build());
        clientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(4000);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);

        ReturnedStringAndDate stringAndDate = new ReturnedStringAndDate();
        stringAndDate.setJsonString(restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class));

    return stringAndDate;
}
}
```

A method to create a list of callables:

```
public List<Callable<ReturnedStringAndDate>> createListOfCallableTasks(PoolList poolList){

    List<Callable<ReturnedStringAndDate>> callableList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < poolList.getPoolList().size(); i++)
        callableList.add(new ConnectToApiCallable(this.appendPoolApiUrl(poolList.getPoolList().get(i)), poolList.getPoolList().get(i).getName()));

    return callableList;
}
```

I am executing the callables via `ExecutorService` interface. The method that executes the pool of tasks:

```
public void storePoolDataToDB(PoolList poolList, Long id) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException{

    List<Future<ReturnedStringAndDate>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        futureList = executorService.invokeAll(this.createListOfCallableTasks(poolList));
    } catch (someExceptionsHere){}

    *some operations on futureList*
}
```

Now, the problem explaination. I do not want to create new Threads for APIs that don't respond indefinietly. My idea is to create a `HashMap` that would include API name as a `key` and a number of errors as a `value`. Depending on the number of errors I would like to delay the next API call. To achieve that I'd have to modify my `createListOfCallableTasks` method.

What I thought of, is having some kind of `dateOfExecution` on a specific API. If there's an error, next call is delayed by 1/2/5/30 minutes. When the task list is formed, I would check the condition:

```
if (executionDate < OffsetDateTime.now()) 
    list.add(task);
else
    continue;
```

Would that be a proper approach?